# Periodic HTML crawl

Tags: php, html, parsing, web-crawler

I'm considering developing a site where the server will crawl another site periodically, in order to gather content for certain entries in my database. My quesitons are as follows...

1. How do you get the server to execute a crawl timely?
2. Can you get it to execute php or what language do you use to perform the crawl?
3. Are there any good APIs to do this?
4. Should I consider building my own? If so, some advice on how to get started would be great

Basically, the kind of thing I want to do, is for the server to execute a script (say every hour), which finds all entries in the database which haven't yet been crawled on another site. It will take a certain value from those entries, and will use them to crawl another site... it might request a url like this: `www.anothersite.com/images?q=entryindb`.

What I want it to do is then crawl the HTML, return an array, and log the values in the database. This is what I want the crawler to look for

```
Find all instances of 
<img> inside <a> inside <td> inside <tr> inside <tbody> inside <table> inside <div id='content'>
Return array of the img.src from all instances.
```

Is something like that possible? - If so, how would I go about doing it? - Please bear in mind that web dev wise, the only experience I have so far (server-side) is with PHP.

**UPDATE**: I will be using a linux-based server, so I guess chron-scripting is how I should do it?

Comment: @Robotsushi I scrape a specific bunch of scripts every day because the devs keep changing it at random times and I want to know when things break. There are entirely legit uses for this.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect work for htmlagilitypack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ but I realize that you want to implement this in PHP

Comment: @Robotsushi - What an overly broad and fallacious statement. It *may be* "stealing" when you use a system in a way that is contrary to the terms of service. However, if a site makes data publicly available, scraping is no more stealing that simply viewing the web page in your browser. Or is your browser stealing when it makes a cache? How about Google's cache... stealing? Wayback machine, criminals? Don't generalize: it never works.

Comment: You should expand on the **3)**. Which part of your question do you want to find an API for, specifically? There's probably 1+ API every part of what you want to do.

Comment: @Chris +1 for "Don't generalize, it never works" LOL :)

Comment: @Chris I can justify plenty of bad programming practices with unique use case examples. There are very few reasons someone really needs to screen scrape. If the company makes data public then they probably offer it in some type of data feed. And i dont see how your childish caching examples helped to prove any kind of point. Obviously caching is not stealing.

Comment: @Incognito source control and good communication would solve this issue.

Comment: @Robotsushi Well, unfortunately I live in reality and the vendor who has a monopoly on this service tore up the contract last time I told them how to do things.

Comment: @Robotsushi - A little ad hominem for spice? "Caching" is a third party making a copy of data for various uses. In what way does scraping the data differ? Rather than dismiss a valid rejoinder as "childish", you can provide some kind of reasoning as to the distinction between the two. Copying a site for later use is copying a site for later use, whether the "later use" is a through a browser, an archive, or what have you. The lack of a data feed does not prove that the company doesn't want anyone to have data - it just proves that they don't have a data feed.

Comment: Caching is used to increase performance which is ultimately tied to usability. Taking other sites content without explict permission is stealing in my opinion and there is a very large difference. I can't say whether the OP intended to do harm with his script however I can say that his goals fall in line with nefarious activities encountered by various shady devs. Your reference to caching was either childish or plain stupid. If you know the difference between screen scraping and caching then its childish to suggest similarity. If you don't know then it's stupidity.

Comment: @Robotsushi - I've contacted the people at the site and they said it's fine - but in this case I'm not going to crawl their site as it's not really necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use cron
2. Yes, you can run a PHP script
3. Nothing like a complete crawling API (AFAIK), but there are classes which will help you parse and traverse DOM documents.
4. You can set something up in minutes if you follow the following steps

#### 1. You need [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to make your life easier with this

Download `phpQuery-0.9.5.386-onefile.zip` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/list).

#### 2. Your PHP file would be something like this

```
require_once 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.othersite.com');
phpQuery::newDocumentXHTML($html);

$elements = pq('#content table tbody tr td a img');
$images = array();
foreach($elements as $img){
    $images[] = pq($img)->attr('src');
}
```

The `$images` array will have a list of all the image sources.

#### 3. Save the above code in a file, say `crawler.php`

Then in the cron tab, if you want the crawler to run every hour, you would do:

```
0 * * * * php /path/to/your/crawler.php
```

Comment: @Alex Coplan: Try that, you might have issues with the CLI php, but if `php /path/to/your/crawler.php` won't work find out the full path of php CLI on your server. If it still won't work with the full path, then try with `curl /path/to/your/crawler.php`. If this doesn't work either, find out the `curl`'s full path. If you don't have `curl`, then try `wget`. Something will/must work for running PHP scripts on your server. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use cron assuming you're hosting on Linux.
2. Yes you can use it to run some PHP.
3. None that I know of, but I've never looked.
4. That's up to you. See the following documentation that I feel might be useful to you.

NOTE: Check with the T+Cs of the sites you want to scrape before hand to see if they allow it.

http://php.net/file_get_contents

http://php.net/curl

http://php.net/domdocument

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch the HTML with [`cURL`](https://www.php.net/curl) (**screenscraping**) and write the HTML parser with php's [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). If the HTML is messy, you can not read it directly with `DOMDocument`, but you could "wash it" with for example [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which takes invalid HTML and spits it out all valid.

To start the process, make your php script able to run via **CLI** (the command line, contrary to a webserver which of course is used for a browser).

After you have this script, setup a **cronjob** (if you have a Linux server) to run your script in what ever period you want.

Google the bolded words.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cron for this. However, PHP might not be the best choice, unless you've already written the script. Python and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) might be most appropriate to scrape the URLs.